# Reconnect to a com port

Tags: arduino-uno, communication

I want my Arduino to log data while connected to a battery.
After few hours, I need to reconnect the Arduino via COM port to a PC and read the logged data.

The com port will not reconnect. This is part of the code I am using. It works if I am not disconnecting the com port. Any idea how to fix this?

```
if (digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH) {
    LoopIndex=0;
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Start printing");
    while (LoopIndex < MinCounter) {
        // print the results to the serial monitor:
        Serial.print("Time = ");
        Serial.print(PressurePerMin[LoopIndex++]);
        Serial.print("\t sensor = ");
        Serial.println(PressurePerMin[LoopIndex++]);
    }
 }
```

Comment: `Serial.begin(9600);` does not "connect". Actually, plugging in/out the USB cable from an Arduino Uno does not affect the Serial port directly. Connecting to the COM port on the PC side might however reset the arduino. (There are several ways to avoid this)

Comment: Your snippet does not show the problem you describe. A minimal but complete test environment is highly recommended.